# A is a set containing n elements. A subset P of A is chosen at random. The set A is reconstructed by replacing the elements of the subset P.

Tags: probability

A subset Q of A is again chosen at random. What's the probability that P∩Q has exactly 2 elements?

What does the sentence "The set A is reconstructed ..... subset P. " even mean?

Comment: "The set $A$ is reconstructed by replacing the elements of the subset $P$" means the drawing is done with replacement. In other words, the set $Q$, which is chosen after $P$, may contain some of the same elements that were chosen for $P$. Anyway, I don't think there is sufficient information until you say what the sizes of $P$ and $Q$ are.

Comment: @JaneDoé Well, P and Q are random subsets of A, so their sizes are not known a priori.